# defined method, not called, still app changed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am reading an iOS tutorial, I have a .h and .m file. In the .m file, I write, define some methods like -

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}
```

or,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChecklistItem"];
    return cell;
}
```

I am not calling these methods anywhere. Still, the output changes on running. How? Are these overriding methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I get your question properly, "you did not call some method but they will be run"
that is true, in `Xcode` you do not call some of the methods and they will be run automatically. when you put one object in your `.xib` there are some related methods that will run on your project. 
If you want to get ride of them you can simply delete them.

Answer (score 4):

These functions have called when you set:

```
yourTableView.delegate = self;
yourTableView.dataSource = self;
```

or connect `yourTableView` to your `File's owner` in the `.xib` file.
Otherwise your `UIView` shows default `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not overriding methods.
Put a breakpoint, go debug and you will see who's calling the method above.

Keep in mind that if you return `1`, a call to the `celForRowAtIndexPath` is always made. Because you have just said that there's one element.

By the way, the methods are being called 'automatically' because you have set the controller to be a `datasource` of your `UITableView`.

Answer (score 2):

These are the Table view delegate methods,,they ill be automatically get called when u set

```
TableViewVar.delegate = self;
TableViewVar.dataSource = self;
```